# How to make image fit in scrollable column?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**What I want:**
I want every image to fit as much as it can in the scrollable column. so the image fit the maximum width it can and the height respectively. I can't figure out how to do this in compose.

**What I tried:**
I only succeed to do this by using a fixed size for the image but this isn't really a solution.

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Blue)) {
    Text(text = "text")

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Red)) {

        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.1),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.size(640.dp)
        )

        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {}
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {}
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {}
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {}
    }

    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `Image` composable to fill the maximum width available you have to use `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()`. That is the same with any Composable.

And then if you also want the **image content** to be scaled in such a way that it fills the maximum width first and then proportionally fills the height as well, you have to pass the `ContentScale.FillWidth` value for the `contentScale` parameter.

Both together in your code

```
Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.1),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
)
```

Another detail that I noticed, if you want the Button below the Column to actually stay on the screen (and not get pushed out by the Column) you have to add the `.weight(1f, fill = true)` modifier to the Column.

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    .fillMaxSize()
    .weight(1f, fill = true)
    .background(Color.Red))
```